# Modify origin of a div

Tags: html, css, sass

I've a div with a css inline style. There is a top and a left position. I need to modify the origin of the div. I want that the top and left must be calculated from the bottom left of my div. Is it possible?

The div has an height that can change.

Comment: Calculated where, when, by whom …? This lacks any sort of useful detail. Please go read [ask], and then rephrase your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the values according to your calculation.

```
$bottomVal:100px;
$topVal:$bottomVal - 10;
$leftVal:$bottomVal - 15;

.parentDiv{
   top:$topVal;
   bottom:$bottomVal;
   left:$leftVal;
}
```